# Attribute asp:Table set to class or void

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner, why in my class and methods are not visible attributes (id, class, table), what to add to the code?

```
 protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchWordDocument searchword = new SearchWordDocument();
        searchword.GetDocumentLibrary();
        //See atribute SearchResult
    }
    public class SearchWordDocument {
        //Create array document
        //Not see atribute SearchResult
        public void GetDocumentLibrary()
        {
         //Not see atribute SearchResult
        {
       }
<asp:Table ID="SearchResult" runat="server" Width="100%"> 
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Type</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>Name</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>Created</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question... What are you trying to do? I mean `ID = SearchResult`, `Class = CssClass` and the `table = asp:Table with ID SearchResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your class should extend from `Page`, and you also should have a partial class with all of your component definitions.

Here's an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" 
OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
    Your gridview here...
</asp:GridView>
```

Now, you should have a partial class right below your .aspx.cs, which is usually under the extension .aspx.designer.cs. This class will be used to declare your components, as it follows:

```
namespace YourApplication {
    //This should have the same name as you .aspx.cs
    public partial class _Default {
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView GridView1;
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to access it.

Comment: Thanks, i will try.